# Unicode asp-classic

Tags: asp-classic

[image]

I'm having problems uploading class in classic asp, I use to upload class upload image files and retrieve data from a form to insert, upload files is ok, but fails Unicode format
 source code  here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/6u67c0hx1ccmfgs/code-aspupload.rar
I have attached the file below, please help me.

Comment: Had the same problem, the upload class wasn't parsing the binary as UTF-8 so had to replace calls to convert binary to string with a UTF-8 version. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37390834/692942

Comment: Also please read [ask] and consider providing a [mcve] of the problem, if you are having to provide external links to source code then the question is not defined enough and likely not on topic for [so].

Answer (score -1):

try adding the following code to your page (sorry, i'm unable to download your attachment at the moment so I can't see if you have it or not)

```
<%
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
%>
```

Comment: That won't do anything, the problem is decoding the binary upload request. If the binary is uploaded and decoded into an ANSI character set because the upload process doesn't support decoding UTF-8 during the parse then whether you set UTF-8 for the response is irrelevant, the damage is already done. You'll just be encoding mismatched ANSI data back to UTF-8.

Comment: <%
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
%>     Yes ,I think  problem not  here !